# TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have gridview that is populated by jquery. Below is part of my code thats giving the above error:

```
var codes = $(this).find("Code").text();

 $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("oTotal").text());
            if ($(this).find("Stock").text() == 'Y') {

                $("td", row).eq(7).html('<a href="#"  class="tooltip" title="This is my divs tooltip message!" id="' + codes + '" style="text-decoration:none">Y</a>');

                 $('#' + codes).live('click', function () {
                    $('#' + codes).tooltip();

                });
            }
            else {
                $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("Stock").text());
            }
```

I am getting an error on $('#'+ codes).tooltip(); I have jquery.ui/1.8.22 and jquery/1.8.3.

Comment: What you exactly need one..?

Comment: Are you certain that you included the tooltip component in your jquery UI loadout?

Comment: Yes I did. I used this CDN http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Can you provide the link to the CDN?

Comment: I searched through the file, tooltip is not in it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think tooltip wasn't part of the file you are pulling in. Are you able to update your CDN reference to jQuery UI to:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by moving all my Javascript tags above:

```
< jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-arranging your script includes so jQuery is first, jQuery UI is second, then along through the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`tooltip()` is not a function!!!

I solved the problem by using below steps in **angular 4**.

install jquery using, `npm install jquery` command.

add the following code in the path src/typings.d.ts file.

```
declare var jquery:any;

interface jquery
{
tooltip(options?:any):any;
}
```

It solved the `tooltip()` issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `tooltip` is the part of Bootstrap so including bootstrap should solve the problem.

Quick links to check with bootstrap, you may remove `https:` from the beginning of the bootstrap links.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tooltip()` has not *always existed in jQuery UI*.  It was added in version 1.9, so it'll work in any version after 1.9.  Proof:

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.

This is why the accepted answer works: it simply links to version 1.10.3.  Ideally, you should be using the most modern version of jQuery UI available (in fact, this rule applies typically to all packages).