# FullCalendar jQuery Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, yii

I am using Yii 2.0 PHP framework and I have a dashboard where I put my calendar. I used a jQuery plugin called FullCalendar for this. But it's not even showing in my page. 
[image]

I used AdminLTE theme's calendar. Under that blue horizontal line should be the calendar. You can look it up here: https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/calendar.html

Here's what I see in the browser console:
[image]

But I already have included all the necessary scripts and css in my page.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

But it's still not working. I don't know what else to do so I'm asking your help. Thanks!

Comment: i think you using another plugin for tooltip. and you didnt include the script for that tooltip

Comment: but the tooltip is not my problem. it's the calendar. it's not showing.

Comment: you have an error on console you need to take care of it so that the calendar will show

Comment: Is that so? okay I will do it.

Comment: @Pekka I have no idea how to get rid of it. I tried. but it's no success. do you have any idea?

Comment: i cant tell without seeing the code but my guess is you are missing a script for the tooltip

Comment: I read this https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/4719 and it says "jQuery tooltip and popover shouldn't be loaded or called when there is no use for it." also this, the top answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279789/typeerror-tooltip-is-not-a-function, I added http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js in my script but still it's no use.

Comment: @Pekka I somehow got rid of the tooltip error, BUT the calendar is still not showing. :(

Comment: like i said it is hard to tell without seeing the code